# Kotshi issue - unresolved reference for KotshiApplicationJsonAdapterFactory

Tags: android, kotlin, moshi

So I'm trying to follow the simple read.me for [Kotshi](https://github.com/ansman/kotshi) and get it set up for my project but I seem to be hitting a little snag. 
I'm currently at this portion of the read.me

```
@KotshiJsonAdapterFactory
object ApplicationJsonAdapterFactory: KotshiApplicationJsonAdapterFactory()
```

but KotshiApplicationJsonAdapterFactory seems to give me an unresolved reference error.  Now this sounds like an absolutely silly question but is KotshiApplicationJsonAdapterFactory supposed to be a custom class that I set up?  If so I don't see anywhere in the documentation regarding it.  My gradle has the two dependencies added so I'm absolutely baffled.

Comment: What is `Kotshi`? Some links please?

Comment: Here's the link!
https://github.com/ansman/kotshi

Comment: Possibly this issue? https://github.com/ansman/kotshi/issues/58

Answer (score 0):

> @KotshiJsonAdapterFactory makes Kotshi generate a JsonAdapter factory.
>   Should be placed on an abstract class that implements
>   JsonAdapter.Factory.

So yes, `KotshiApplicationJsonAdapterFactory` is a custom `class` that you've to setup and which fulfills the above condition.

Answer (score 0):

`KotshiJsonAdapterFactory` is an annotation that you apply to a class that you write. This will make Kotshi generate a class with the same name as your class + the `Kotshi` prefix. That class will implement the actual factory.

When you write your class it will look like you have a compile error, but it will not prevent compilation.